# Catch-all helper for Makefile when the possible arguments can include a colon character (:)

Tags: makefile

Trying to improve the Makefile for my project so I can execute certain commands directly within the docker container actually running the application.

So far I have a solution that works for stuff like:

```
$ make composer update
$ make console help
```

This is the relevant part of the `Makefile` so far:

```
# if the command starts with "composer" or console, grab the arguments for the command
ifeq ($(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS)), $(filter $(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS)), console composer))
    # use the rest as arguments for our real command
    COMMAND_ARGS := $(wordlist 2,$(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)),$(MAKECMDGOALS))
    # turn them into null targets 
    $(eval $(COMMAND_ARGS):;@:)
endif 

console: ## execute bin console within the APP/PHP container
    docker-compose exec core19app sh -c "php bin/console $(COMMAND_ARGS)"

composer: ## execute container's console 
    docker-compose exec core19app sh -c "composer $(COMMAND_ARGS)"
```

Problem is, `console` commands are Symfony commands, which in almost all cases include a `:` character.

E.g.:

```
$ make console cache:clear
$ make console messenger:consume
```

And trying to execute any of these will choke make, which will sadly report that:

> Makefile:6: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.

The problem lies with us auto-registering empty tasks for the called command on the fly, and since the variable command includes a `:`, `make` chokes.

Trying to keep this as **close as possible** to `make console command:sucommand` with us keeping everything within the `Makefile`, although variations could be used, trying to keep the friction as low as possible

Comment: Sounds like you don't actually want to build `cache:clear` as a target; why not just pass in an ordinary variable?  E.g. `make console CONSOLE_ARGS=cache:clear`

Comment: Basically, because it's more verbose? Could work if there were no other way to accomplish this. But using the commands the same way as I'd use them if I didn't have to go through docker would be much more convenient and really help with muscle memory.

Comment: And no, I don't want `cache:clear` to be a target, nor any of the couple of dozen commands `console` provide (all of them like `namespace:command`)

Comment: "Because it's more verbose" ⟶ you could use a shell function or script to create and execute the `make` command from the syntax you'd like.  It's not clear that `make` is the tool you want at all (I don't see any dependencies).

Comment: If I get you right, you want just the first command line argument to be a true target to make. Why not write a simple shell wrapper instead of some ill-fated programming-against-good-make-habits ? Yup, what @TobySpeight said.

Comment: Ill fated or not, it would be very convenient, easy to remember, and would use exactly the same syntax that we are already familiarized with for those commands. Would also be self contained, all these helper commands are centralized here and there is no need (so far) to have other extraneous files with other definitions. If not possible, other solutions are also welcome. The objective is to be able to type `make console command:subcommand` or `make composer command` and the appropriate one be executed within the container.

Comment: Don't concern yourself with that. Our team and anyone who comes on board will always be more familiarized with  `console` or `composer` syntax than with `make`. This is just to provide a convenience layer. If you do not know how to get around this, no problem. Thanks anyway for trying.

Comment: _will always be more familiarized with console or composer syntax than with make_  to me this means that your argument against a shell wrapper is none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably get more mileage leveraging make invocation conventions (which expect make to take list of targets to build). It's going to be hard to different argument style. Consider the alternatives:

Using variable to pass parameter to the console

```
make console CMD=cache:clear

Makefile:
console:
    docker-compose exec core19app sh -c "php bin/console $(CMD)"
```

Or using pseudo-targets cmd-SOMETHING

```
make console-cache:clear

Makefile
console-%:
    docker-compose exec core19app sh -c "php bin/console $(@:console-%=%)"
```

As last resort, consider small wrapper 'make-console' to make for more friendly command line interface, if users need it.

```
#! /bin/sh
make console CMD="$1"
```

Comment: Thanks. Would be lovely to be able to make the above work. Pseudo targets are similar enough, and if nothing else worked we'd be able to live with that. But it doesn't really work as it is. E.g. executing `make console-debug:config` tries to execute `php bin/console console-debug:config` instead of `php bin/console console debug:config` as it should.

Comment: @yivi Oops, I had a typo - sorry, see updated code, which will strip console-% from the target. My initial implementation was using 'cmd-*' as a prefix.

Answer (score 2):

```
ifneq ($(if $(MAKECMDGOALS),$(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)),1),1)
.SUFFIXES:
TARGET := $(if $(findstring :,$(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS))),,$(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS))) 
PARAMS := $(if $(findstring :,$(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS))),$(MAKECMDGOALS),$(wordlist 2,100000,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
.PHONY: ONLY_ONCE
ONLY_ONCE:
    $(MAKE) $(TARGET) COMMAND_ARGS="$(PARAMS)"
%: ONLY_ONCE
    @:
else
# Your previous makefile goes here:
.PHONY: console composer

console: ## execute bin console within the APP/PHP container
    docker-compose exec core19app sh -c "php bin/console $(COMMAND_ARGS)"

composer: ## execute container's console 
    docker-compose exec core19app sh -c "composer $(COMMAND_ARGS)"

endif
```

This solution will only work for at most one target, given as first parameter on the command line (or none)

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
ifeq ($(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS)), $(filter $(firstword $(MAKECMDGOALS)), console composer))
    COMMAND_ARGS := $(wordlist 2,$(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)),$(MAKECMDGOALS))
endif 

console:
    @docker-compose exec core19app sh -c "php bin/console $(COMMAND_ARGS)"

composer:
    @docker-compose exec core19app sh -c "composer $(COMMAND_ARGS)"

%:
    @:
```

seems to to what you want.  I don't guarantee that there won't be unwanted side effects with the part of the `Makefile` you deemed irrelevant and I agree with those suggesting that you are abusing `make` to do things it has not been designed for.  I'd probably use my own script, wrapping around `make` and `docker-compose`.  A simplified version would be:

```
#! /bin/sh

case "$1" in
    console)
       shift
       docker-compose exec core19app sh -c "php bin/console $*"
       ;;
    composer)
       shift
       docker-compose exec core19app sh -c "composer $*"
       ;;
    *)
       make "$@"
       ;;
esac
```

Comment: It's not that I want to disregard anything. But there are already a lot of other things built into this makefile (not to mention internal documentation) that make putting stuff outside less appealing. (Lose built-in auto-complete for make targets, we have a "help" target that lists all the available commands, etc). In regards what "make was designed for"... I believe this is a valid use case for the tool, even if we are hitting its limits. Thanks a lot for your help, I'll see what of this we can use.